# Adding minimal subsets to $\aleph_\omega$

Tags: lo.logic, set-theory, forcing, large-cardinals

Given a cardinal $\kappa,$ recall that $X \subset \kappa$ is called fresh (over $V$), if $X \notin V,$ but $X \cap \alpha \in V$ for all 
$\alpha < \kappa.$

**Question.** Is it consistent that there exists a generic extension $V[G]$
of $V$ (for some suitable $V$), such that:

**(A)** $V$ and $V[G]$ have the same cardinals and cofinalities,

**(B)** $V$ and $V[G]$ have the same bounded subsets of $\aleph_\omega,$

**(C)** There exists a fresh subset $X \in V[G]$ of $\aleph_\omega$ (over $V$), such that $V[G]=V[X],$ and $V[G]$ is a minimal generic extension of $V?$

**Remark.** See [A minimal Prikry-type forcing for singularizing a measurable cardinal](http://projecteuclid.org/euclid.jsl/1358951101) and [Prikry-type forcing and minimal $α$-degree](http://arxiv.org/abs/1310.0891), where some 
similar results for a large singular cardinal are proved.

Comment: (+1) What is the difficulty of reformulating the same methods that work for large singular cardinals in the case of smaller singulars like $\aleph_{\omega}$?